# dpkg sent over SSH on Mac App not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ssh, dpkg

So I am facing a very strange peculiarity. I am trying to run dpkg on a remote server via SSH. My code works perfectly if I click Run through Xcode, but if I click Build > Archive then Export as a Mac Application, all SSH commands sent to the server work, other than "dpkg". Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Did you check all paths that are used in your app and script?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code which is trying to run this dpkg command (and the other commands that work)?

Comment: Thank you guys for your interest. So, after many days I figured out what's the issue. So, transferring the file via scp from the app was problematic and what made the trick was using curl to get the file directly and then run dpkg. Why dpkg wouldn't work with the scp transferred file remains to be learnt though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after many days of facing that issue, I tried installing via dpkg a Deb that was already located on my server and it worked. What's even more strange is that while scp would transfer the file, dpkg would just not use it! What made the trick was getting the file via curl and then running dpkg normally. No idea why that's the case though, as both Deb files had the same owner, group and permissions. And both were running by root, so it wasn't a permission error.